# Styles not getting applied

Tags: jquery, css, jsp

I have a jsp page where I have kept my code for horizontal tabs. Styles and jquery.js have been applied via tiles.xml.

```
<put-list-attribute name="scripts"> 
        <add-attribute value="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" />
        <add-attribute value="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js" />
        <add-attribute value="/scripts/jquery.limit-1.2.js" />
        <add-attribute value="/scripts/json2.js" /> 
        <add-attribute value="/scripts/commonScripts.js" />
</put-list-attribute>
```

After the scripts, i have mentioned css files

```
<put-list-attribute name="styles">
<add-attribute value="/css/menu.css" />
<add-attribute value="/css/jquery-ui.css" />
<add-attribute value="/css/cStyle.css" /> 
<add-attribute value="/css/appStyle.css" /> 
</put-list-attribute>
```

Css files are in webcontent folder where other css are present. styles for the tabs are in jquery-ui.css in the webcontent folder. For header, footer styles are in other css. Only the css that has been applied for tabs are not working. Can someone suggest what is wrong with the code ?

Comment: Check the browser output with Firebug in Firefox or Webtools in Chrome.

Comment: it shows a gif is missing. but that is not related to the one I work with.

Comment: I meant with my words check the executed css. Firebug and Chrome's Webtools console gives you the oppotunity to check the applied css styles on each html element. Maybe there are some styles has been overwritten, are invalid or missing.

Comment: Yes I see that Styles have been overwritten. I am trying to change the names out to fix those.